# What are best practices for handling unknown URLs in a web application?

Tags: express, redirect

I have a web application generated by the [Angular Fullstack Generator](https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack). If the ExpressJS server gets a request for an unknown URL for some specific directories, it will return a 404:

```
app.route('/:url(api|auth|components|app|bower_components|assets)/*')
    .get(errors[404]);
```

For all other unknown routes, it just redirects to the homepage:

```
app.route('/*')
    .get(function(req, res) {
        res.sendfile(path.resolve(app.get('appPath') + '/index.html'));
    });
```

Is this a good idea? The reason I ask is because Google has reported my site as maybe being hacked. It keeps trying to fetch URLS like http://andrewkoroluk.com/survival-games-1-e7733-map, and when it gets a 200 OK response, it marks the site.

Comment: _“Is this a good idea?”_ – no, of course not. It should return a 404 status code for _anything_ that doesn’t exist, not only for a select few routes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The RFC of HTTP states you must return 404 when not found.

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.5

This is not good or bad practice, this is mandatory